# Case insensitive string search of dictionary

Tags: python, search, dictionary, python-3.x

I have a large dictionary that I am searching through to find a specific string. The keys for the dictionary are numbers and then the values are tuples. How would I create a function to loop through the dictionary using a case-insensitive search then take the keys that contain the relevant phrase, and add them to a new list? I would like to use this new list [match] in a subsequent function (show) that I have created to print the information.

My code looks like this:

```
dict = {
1 : (value,value,value),
2 : (value,value,value),
so on...
}
# searches dict, criteria determines whether search is for str() or int(), phrase is string I am searching for
def search(criteria,phrase):

    enter code here

# prints new list
def show(match):
```

Comment: Your idea sounds like a good solution, yes.

Comment: How would you suggest doing this? My code for the dictionary looks like this:

dict = {
key : (value,value,value),
key : (value,value,value),
... so on
}

Comment: I can't see your code, add it in an edit of your post!

Comment: Fixed it sorry about that

Comment: So, if you look for `"abc"`, a search in `d = {k1: ("abc", "123", "cde"), k2: ("ljfdal", "jlkbjlaf", "jljga") }` should return `k1` right?

Comment: Could you perhaps edit your question with an example of such dictionary?

Comment: Your edited question still isn't very helpful. If all of your keys are integers, which means they can't possibly contain any phrase, so you just loop over nothing. And you haven't shown us what you expect the output of the function to be, or told us what the parameters mean.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> d = {1: ("one", "two", "three"), 2: ("four", "five", "six")}
>>> [i for i, j in d.items() if 'two' in j]
[1]
```

---

As a function:

```
def search(criteria, phrase):
    return [i for i, j in criteria.items() if phrase in j]
```

Comment: Rather: `... in j.lower()`.

Comment: @Tadeck The question is a bit unclear at this stage, so I'll wait for the OP to reply.

Comment: You are right. My correction was based on the title ("_Case insensitive string search of dictionary_"), but it is worth clarifying. I also think the values are strings, not tuples of strings - this is a guess.

Comment: the values of the dictionary are tuples. Do you think that the answer below would work for something like this?

Comment: @EduardoVasquez I'm not sure, but does my solution work in your circumstance? I'm just clarifying, because the question is a tad unclear

Comment: The values of each key are tuples and I am searching for a specific phrase (string) that are stored in the tuples of each key. Does that clear it up?

Comment: @EduardoVasquez Yes, isn't that what my answer does?

Comment: @EduardoVasquez: Instead of making everyone guess what your data look like and dropping little hints every time their guesses are wrong, why not edit your question to show actual sample data, and the expected results?

Comment: @EduardoVasquez So my answer should be fine

Comment: @Haidro sorry I am new to python and am having trouble putting this into a function. I have created a function that looks like this and defined my two arguments in the parantheses below:   
def search(criteria,phrase):

Comment: @EduardoVasquez I have edited my question. I'm presuming `criteria` is the dictionary and `phrase` is what you're trying to find

Comment: @Haidro I have edited my original question hope this clears everything up

Comment: @EduardoVasquez I'm still confused. Tell me if my code is working or not. If not, why isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work! It works in O(n) time so it won't get any better :)

```
phrase = phrase.lower() # the matching value made lowercase (case insensitivity)
matches = []

lowerDict = {} # makes the dict lowercase
for key in dictionary:
  lowerDict[key] = [s.lower() for s in dictionary[key]]

for key in lowerDict:
  if phrase in lowerDict[key]:
    matches.append(key)

for match in matches:
  print(dictionary[match])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for except when I try to run it python gives me an Attribute error. Since the key is an int data type it tells me that it has no 'lower' attribute

Comment: But s is not an int. It's actually a "value" if you have defined your data correctly.