# Case-insensitive matching of dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Re `.lower` usage (?), how can I make **case-insensitive matching** for dictionary values? For example, `config[camID]["media_file"]]` should match both, lowercase and uppercase extensions, even though the dictionary has lowercase only.

1 line from dictionary:

```
config['d5']['media_file'] = ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')
```

Code:

```
for f in files:
     if any([f.endswith(x) for x in config[camID]["media_file"]]):
         os.rename(os.path.join(path, f), 
                   os.path.join(path, "%s%s%s" % (config[camID]['cam_name'], "_", f)))
```

(If there is an "in-dictionary" solution (i.e, instead in the code), that would be also interesting to know.)

Comment: use `f.lower().endswith(x)`?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355312/case-insensitive-string-search-of-dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the data to a standard before stores in the dict (like lower). After storage there is no way to search for case insensitive inside dict ou set, because this search are made by hash.